# Ruby - One code block works, one gives error?

Tags: ruby

This code works fine :-

```
def rps_tournament_winner(tournament)
    if tournament[0][0].kind_of?(String)
       puts game_winner tournament
    else 
      for i in 0..tournament.length-1
        rps_tournament_winner tournament[i]
      end
    end
end
```

However this code give me the following error
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting kDO or '{' or '('

```
def rps_tournament_winner(tournament)
  array = []
    if tournament[0][0].kind_of?(String)
       array << game_winner tournament
    else 
      for i in 0..tournament.length-1
        rps_tournament_winner tournament[i]
      end
    end
end
```

Can someone please explain why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a parsing issue. Use parentheses to clarify:

```
array << game_winner(tournament)
```